# How prove this $FC\bot AO$

Tags: geometry

let $GH$ is  the diameter of the circle $O$,and such
$$AB\bot GH,FD\bot GH,AB=CD$$

show that
$$FC\bot AO$$

[image]

My try:
since $$AB//FD$$
we only prove

$$\angle AOB=\angle CFD$$
or
$$\angle BAO+\angle CFD=90$$
But My I can't,Thank you

Comment: I cannot access the image in the question(security issue). Can you define the points $O$ and $C$ ?

Comment: @lsp $O$ is the circle's center, $C$ is a point on $AO$.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a while thinking about this question and tried constructing various cases. My approach is essentially the same as [Toan Nguyen Dinh](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/118406/toan-nguyen-dinh)'s, even though I thought it'd be helpful to describe the motivation of proof.

I suspected that the point $C$ is unique. The next step was to convince myself why this was so. In order to do this, I considered points $P$ lying on $\overline{AO}$ and the associated pair of angle and distance $(\angle APF,\overline{PD})$. Thus it sufficed to show that for any point $P$, there exists a unique pair $(\angle APF,\overline{PD})$. But this is easy to show based on the diagram above. In particular, it follows easily from the fact that $D$ lies on the opposite side of the centre $O$ with respect to $B$. (So $\angle AOD$ is obtuse and there can be no line of symmetry/bisection for the segment $\overline{AO}$ that passes through $D$, implying that the function $f:\overline{AO}\rightarrow\mathbb R^+$ that maps the point $P\in \overline{AO}$ to its associated segment length $\overline{PD}$ is injective. In particular, if a point $C$ is chosen such that $\angle FCA=90^\circ$ and we subsequently find that $\overline{CD}=\overline{AB}$, then this point is uniquely determined and the converse - that $\overline{CD}=\overline{AB}\Rightarrow \angle FCA=90^\circ$ - follows. Remark that $\overline{AB}$ is a fixed length.)

It's useful to notice that this argument does not work when $D$ lies on the same side of $O$ with respect to $B$; try placing $D$ to the left of $B$ in the diagram above. (More precisely, now $\angle AOD$ is acute and we can draw a line of symmetry for $\overline{AO}$ that passes through $D$, giving us two possible points $C_1,C_2$ lying on $\overline{AO}$ for which $\overline{C_1D}=\overline{C_2D}=\overline{AB}$. In this case, it's not always true that $\angle FCA=90^\circ$, and one has to discuss further which point gives rise to the perpendicularity...)

Answer (score 0):

Which grade are you in ? If you learnt about the $sin$ function.

A short proof is here:
**Proof**
Choose $C' $ lying in segment $ AO$ such that $FC' \perp AO$.
We see that $FO$ is the diameter of circumcircle of $C'OD$.
Therefore $C'D=FOsin\angle C'OD =AO .sin\angle AOB=AB$.

 Hence $C' \equiv C$.
Done

**Thank to ir7, i think i should write down something about the hypothesis of this problem:**
I think the problem you include the condition that :*$O$ lies between $B,D$* .To make sure there is only one point $C$ that sasifies the hypothesis of the problem. :)

Comment: DC' = DC does not immediately imply C=C', even if C and C' lie on the same line (needs some argument).

Answer (score 0):

You can take the "brute force" way with coordinates and show that the scalar product $\vec{OA}  \cdot \vec{CF}$ is $0$. If you are unfamiliar with the dot product, this is equivalent to showing that slope of $CF$ equals minus the reciprocal of the slope of $AO$, which implies crossing at a right angle.

Let without loss of generality $O$ be at $(0|0)$ and $GO = OH = 1$. Also $B(x_B|0)$, $A(x_B|\sqrt{1-x_B^2})$, $D(x_D|0)$, $F(x_D,\sqrt{1-x_D^2})$.

Then there is a scalar factor $c$ such that $C$ is at $(cx_B|c\sqrt{1-x_B^2})$.
Calculate the length of $CD$, set equal to $AB$, solve the resulting quadratic equation* for $c$ (there will be two values, since there is another point on the extension of $OA$ at distance $|AB|$ from $D$, in your picture south of $GH$).

Then calculate $\vec{OA}  \cdot \vec{CF}$ (or show that $\frac{y_A-y_O}{x_A-x_O}=-1/\frac{y_C-y_F}{x_C-x_F}$) and notice how conveniently the expression for $c$ you just derived can be inserted.

*$c^2-2cx_Bx_D+x_B^2+x_D^2-1=0$ is the one I arrived at, for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It can be proven geometrically as follow.

1. Since $\angle AOB + \angle COD = 180°$ and $AB = CD$ , $\triangle OAB$ and $\triangle ODC$ is inscribed in a circle with a same diameter.
2. Also from,  $OA=OF$ and $\angle ABO = \angle ODF = 90°$, we see that $\triangle OAB$ and $\triangle ODF$ is inscribed in a circle with a same diameter as well.
3. Hence, since $\triangle ODC$ and  $\triangle ODF$ shares a same side $OD$, $\triangle ODC$ and  $\triangle ODF$ is inscribed in the same circle.
4. Therefore, $\angle ODF + \angle OCF=180°　\Leftrightarrow \angle OCF=90°$